# SequelizeEagerLoadingError, can't get data with include

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize.js to make requests to database. I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables, and I made a third junction table. Here are my three tables. polit_in_article is the junction table.

politician.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Politician = sequelize.define('politician', {
        ...
    });

    Politician.associate = (models) => {
        Politician.hasMany(models.Polit_in_article, {
            foreignKey: 'politicianId',
            as: 'polit_in_articles',
        });
    };

    return Politician;
};
```

article.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Article = sequelize.define('article', {
        ...
    });

    Article.associate = (models) => {
        Article.hasMany(models.Politician, {
            foreignKey: 'articleId',
            as: 'polit_in_articles'
        });
    };
    return Article;
};
```

polit_in_article.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Polit_in_article = sequelize.define('polit_in_article', {
        times_mentioned: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    });
    Polit_in_article.associate = (models) => {
        Polit_in_article.belongsTo(models.Article, {
            // foreignKey: 'articleId',
            as: 'articles',
        });
        Polit_in_article.belongsTo(models.Politician, {
            // foreignKey: 'politicianId',
            as: 'politicians',
        });
    };

    return Polit_in_article;
};
```

And here is my controller(not sure if that is the right way to call it):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Article = require('../models').Article;
const Politician = require('../models').Politician;
const Polit_in_article = require('../models').Polit_in_article;

const Op = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = {
    getAllArticlesOfPolitician(req) {
        return Article
            .findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: Polit_in_article,
                    include: [{
                        model: Politician,
                        where: {
                            lastname: req.query.politicianLastName,
                        }
                    }],
                }],
            }).then(response => response)
            // .catch(err => err);
    }
};
```

and with this I get an error `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: polit_in_article is not associated to article`. It is possible that I missed something, but I really don't know what to do here. I have tried to make the articles table to have association `as: 'polit_in_articles'`, that worked until I needed to include the politicians tabel in to the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `through` keyword in your associations. `Articles` will have `politicians` `through` the `Polit_in_article` model, however since you are just using the primary keys on it you can let it be inferred and leave out `polit_in_article.js` and just use a string to name the table.

```
Politician.associate = (models) => {
  Politician.hasMany(models.Article, {
    foreignKey: 'politicianId',
    through: 'polit_in_article',
    as: 'articles',
  });
};

Article.associate = (models) => {
  Article.hasMany(models.Politician, {
    foreignKey: 'articleId',
    through: 'polit_in_article',
    as: 'politicians',
  });
};
```

Now you can query through the join table by specifying `as` and `through`.

```
getAllArticlesOfPolitician(req) {
  return Article.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Politician,
      as: 'politicians',
      through: 'polit_in_article',
      where: {
        lastname: req.query.politicianLastName,
      },
    }],
  })
  .then(response => response)
  .catch(err => err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to fix association in article.js, I made association with politician instead of the junction table:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const Article = sequelize.define('article', {
         ...
    });

    Article.associate = (models) => {
        Article.hasMany(models.Polit_in_article, {
            foreignKey: 'articleId',
            as: 'polit_in_articles'
        });
    };
    return Article;
};
```